# NodeJS unable to get

Tags: node.js

new to NodeJS and I am trying to get a basic endpoint going.  I actually have three different controllers, but one of them will not work.  Here is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var db = require('./db');
var config = require('./config/config'); // get config file

global.__root   = __dirname + '/';

var ApiController = require(__root + 'auth/ApiController');
app.use('/api/auth', ApiController);

var UserController = require(__root + 'user/UserController');
app.use('/api/users', UserController);

var AuthController = require(__root + 'auth/AuthController');
app.use('/api/auth/users', AuthController);

module.exports = app;
```

The UserController and AuthController work great but the ApiController:

```
//this controller handles api token
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.get('/apiToken') , function(req, res) {
    console.log("received request at /apiToken");
    res.status(200).send({ token: config.api.token });
};

module.exports = router;
```

When I try this in Postman you can see:
[image]

I know it has to be something really simple because the failing call is nearly identical to the working ones - but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a coding mistake here with a closing paren in the wrong place on this line that happens to not make an interpreter error, but does not execute as intended:

```
router.get('/apiToken') , function(req, res) {
//               here ^
```

So change this:

```
router.get('/apiToken') , function(req, res) {
    console.log("received request at /apiToken");
    res.status(200).send({ token: config.api.token });
};
```

to this:

```
router.get('/apiToken', function(req, res) {
    console.log("received request at /apiToken");
    res.send({ token: config.api.token });
});
```

FYI, there is no need to do `res.status(200)` as that is the default status already.  You can just use `res.send(...)` and the status will be set to 200 automatically.  You only need to use `res.status(xxx)` when you want the status to be something other than 200.

Also, running your code though something like jshint will often complain about these types of mistakes that (somewhat by accident) don't throw an interpreter error.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew fresh and more experienced eyes would catch that dumb mistake.  I'll look at the status code as well.

Comment: @jfriend00 you're answering a question "you have a typo" and are wondering why you got a downvote?

Comment: @sonoerin - I wasn't addressing my comment at you.  I was just asking a question of whoever downvoted.  Lovely, now there's a flood of downvotes and I can't even delete an accepted answer.  Sometimes you do feel punished here for just helping someone.  To others, please note, there are two other aspects to this answer besides pointing out the coding error.